# A question regarding Similar Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBzN1.jpg)

> Suppose there exist a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and a $3$-dimensional column-vector $x$ such that the set of vectors $x,Ax,A^2x$ are linearly independent, and
> $$
> A^3x = 3Ax - 2A^2 x
> $$
>
> 1. Let $P = [x,\ Ax, \ A^2 x].$ Find a matrix $B$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$.
> 2. Compute the determinant $|A^2 + A + I|$.

Can you please tell me how to proceed ? I can only conclude from the given information that $A$ is singular.

Comment: As you might have noticed based on the closure of your previous questions, users are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained in detail here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address any of the following. Where did you encounter this question? What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far? You have given us some information towards that last question, but it would be helpful if you explained how you concluded that $A$ is singular.

Comment: I also suspect based on your previous question that you are aware that users are expected to format mathematical expressions using Mathjax, and that instructions on how to do so are [given here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I have gone through the trouble of formatting this post, but I would recommend that you eventually put the effort into learning how to do this yourself.

Comment: As a hint for how to begin answering this question: each of the equations
$$
A(x) = 0x + Ax + 0A^2 x\\
A(Ax) = 0x + 0Ax + A^2x\\
A(A^2 x) = 0 x  +3Ax - 2A^2 x
$$
can be used to find a column of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually easier to find $B$ such that $AP=PB$. Notice that $$\begin{eqnarray*} AP &=& A[x,Ax,A^2x]\\ &=&[Ax,A^2x,A^3x]\\ &=& [Ax,A^2x,3Ax-2A^2x]\\ &=&PB \end{eqnarray*}$$ where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 1&0&3\\ 0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$. This means we can say $$\begin{eqnarray*} \det(A^2+A+I)&=&\det(P[B^2+B+I]P^{-1}) \\&=& \det(B^2+B+I) \\ &=& \det\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 1&4&-3\\ 1&-1&6\end{pmatrix} \\ &=& 21 \end{eqnarray*}$$